# How can I get igraph to stop crashing with large graphs?

Tags: r, igraph

I am working with a rather large network in igraph (around 200,000 edges). I am computing a version of closeness centrality (harmonic centrality), as follows:

```
#Create igraph network object:
g <- graph.edgelist(as.matrix(d), directed = FALSE)
g <- simplify(g)

#Normalized harmonic centrality:
h <- 1/(shortest.paths(g))
h[!is.finite(h)] <- 0
h <- (colSums(h)/gorder(h))
```

However, this crashes R. In fact, any network measure applied to the whole network crashes R. I can work with the largest connected component (about 7,000 edges) without a problem, but not with the whole network. I'm using harmonic centrality (rather than igraph's built-in centrality measure) as it's more appropriate for disconnected graphs.

I am trying to figure out a workaround for this. One option is to perhaps split the network up into its constituent components, and then run my harmonic centrality measure. But after trying:

```
decompose.graph(g)
```

R crashes again. I normally work in R Studio but I've also tried this in the vanilla, non-GUI R; but with the same result.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can get around this?

Answer (score 0):

large graphs occupy a lot of memory. thus, first your OS must be 64bit and if your memory is low, maybe you need to use virtual memory and increase the Swapfile size.